# How do you win the baby rocking minigame in Tomodachi Life?

Tags: tomodachi-life

I am having trouble figuring out the motion for the baby rocking minigame in Tomodachi Life. I have tried swaying, both by holding my hands steady and rocking my hips as well as by moving the 3DS side-to-side. I have also tried rotating the 3DS up and down or back and forth slightly. I can't get the baby to stop crying! Does anyone know what I'm supposed to be doing?

*Edit*: It seems it's hard to describe how to do this so let me give a prompt. How should I initially be holding my 3DS (flat as if it were on a table, the top screen perfectly parallel to my face, or something in between), and in what direction should I be moving it, both in three-dimensional space as well as on its three-dimensional axis?

I managed to get it after a fluke so I still don't know the "correct" way to do it, so I'm still looking for answers.

Comment: @AshleyNunn thanks for the tag creation. I would have done it myself, but I couldn't!

Comment: Don't shake the baby!

Comment: @DoozerBlake Thanks for letting me know. I was **just** about to try throttling my 3DS, too!

Comment: I WANT TO GET THIS GAME. BADLY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually hold it however I hold it normally so the screen is open to that first "click" and I just move up and down (closer to the floor then move up towards the ceiling) in small movements about the length of my stomach starting slow and getting faster until you find the right pace the baby likes.

Don't try to over think it too much.

Comment: Thanks, I did something similar to your suggestion and it worked somewhat consistently (more often than not.) Basically, I did the same thing, but I let it move in a small arc too.

Answer (score 1):

What has worked best for me is to rotate the DS so that it lays like a book. As I am right-handed, I grip the lower portion of the DS (the right side of the "book") with one hand and move the DS in an up-down (floor to ceiling) motion. I don't go very far - travelling maybe 6 inches vertically. The rate/rhythm I move at is faster than I would have expected, but the babies tend to be smiling with just a few small adjustments each time.

Comment: Besides rotating the DS I did something similar to your suggestion and had some luck. As I mentioned in lovely's suggestion I added a small arc.

Comment: @2rs2ts I experimented with a new technique last night where I held it like a book and then just rotated my hand, bending the wrist 90 degrees (keeping the ds flat). I had phenomenal results, but I want to do some more testing before I update my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I sort of did that, maybe like a 45 degree arc around an imaginary radius... hard to describe, but it was kind of like moving up and down the middle part of the letter C.

Answer (score 0):

According to a post on [GameFAQS](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/643013-tomodachi-life/69656436)

> Rock the 3DS from side to side (just tilting it is fine)
>
> If you're doing it right you'll see the arms lift and drop. Each time the baby has a different rhythm you need to find and keep. Just tilt it like you'd tilt a Mario Kart wheel when steering. back and forth, back and forth. Find a speed AND distance of tilting. When it sparkles once, keep that pace up until it stops crying.
>
> Same with tickles, pats, and peekaboos. Sometimes you need to tickle, sometimes pat, sometimes peekaboo. Another thing that's not said is sometimes you need to flick their noses up. Just flick the stylus quickly across the nose to "boop" it. That works from time to time too.

Answer (score -2):

Or you could hold the 3ds like the bottom screen shows and swing your arms back and forth like it's a **real** baby. It's not rocket science you know.... Although I can see why this little mini game can be frustrating.

Comment: I did just this, which of course didn't work.

Answer (score -3):

You put the 3DS up and down, and see which pace it appreciates the best. That pace is the one you should continue, up and down.

Comment: This is so not helpful. Do you mean I should lay the system flat then elevate it?